# Repeated Measures ANOVA?

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, t-test, paired-comparisons, psychology

I am an undergraduate student studying psychology using SPSS to analyse my data.

I have 2 conditions of the IV of treatment (treatment or no treatment) to test pain tolerance levels which is measured by the DV of pulse rate to measure pain.

The study used a repeated measrures design using a counterbalancing approach (e.g. 20 particpants in treatment condition first, wheras other 20 in no treatment condition first, and then in alternate condition in second part of experiment. The sample is two-thirds consisting of females and one-third of males, although i want to analyse gender differences anayway.

I've used paired samples t-tests to test for significant differences between both conditions, but now i want to test it for gender differences, to see if whether male or female particpants got higher scores.

Is there any ANOVA's i would use for this and how would i interpret it using what tests?

Comment: Why not regression analysis keeping treatment category, baseline pulse rate and gender as independent variables and final pulse rate (or change in pulse rate) as dependent variable.

Comment: What is IV and DV here?

Comment: The original IV is treatment condition with 2 levels - treatment condition and no treatment condition (using repeated measures design)

The DV is pain tolernace measured by multiple measures of questionnaire scores and time as well as blood pressure.


I originally used a series of paired samples t-test (and non-parametric Wilcoxon-Signed Ranks Test) to analyse for any significant differences. However, I want to add another IV of gender to analyse any differences between males and females. Is there any paramtric and non-parametric tests for this?

Does anyone know the process for this in SPSS?